# Python NameError: name is not defined - method not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working from a book, very much newbie stuff, and the code below is from the book, and defines a simple class. But for *some reason*, the author has decided to put a "helper method" called `check_index` outside the class. I cannot for the life of me figure out why he would do this, as the method seems integral to teh operation of the class. He writes:

> The index checking is taken care of by a utility function I’ve written
>   for the purpose, check_index.

I have tried putting it inside the class (the code below is as it is in the book), but the runtime refuses to find the method - it falls over with

```
NameError: name 'check_index' is not defined
```

My questions are, why did the author put this "helper method" outside the class, and why does the code not work when I move the method inside the class:

```
class ArithmeticSequence:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.start = start # Store the start value
        self.step = step # Store the step value
        self.changed = {} # No items have been modified      
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        check_index(key)
        try: return self.changed[key] # Modified?
        except KeyError: # otherwise ...
            return self.start + key * self.step # ... calculate the value
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        check_index(key)
        self.changed[key] = value # Store the changed value


def check_index(key):
    if not isinstance(key, int): raise TypeError
    if key < 0: raise IndexError
```

When I move the method inside the class, I just slot it in with the other methods. But it is not found by the runtime. Why?

```
class ArithmeticSequence:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.start = start # Store the start value
        self.step = step # Store the step value
        self.changed = {} # No items have been modified
    def check_index(key):
        if not isinstance(key, int): raise TypeError
        if key < 0: raise IndexError        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        check_index(key)
        try: return self.changed[key] # Modified?
        except KeyError: # otherwise ...
            return self.start + key * self.step # ... calculate the value
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        check_index(key)
        self.changed[key] = value # Store the changed value
```

Comment: In your class implementation, each method is `instance` method. Why there is no `self` parameter in your `check_index(self, key).

Comment: I tried it with check_error(self,key) - that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to call with `self.check_index...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `self`

**Ex:**

```
class ArithmeticSequence:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.start = start # Store the start value
        self.step = step # Store the step value
        self.changed = {} # No items have been modified
    def check_index(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, int): raise TypeError
        if key < 0: raise IndexError        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.check_index(key)
        try: return self.changed[key] # Modified?
        except KeyError: # otherwise ...
            return self.start + key * self.step # ... calculate the value
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.check_index(key)
        self.changed[key] = value # Store the changed value
```

- And call the function with self Ex: `self.check_index`

Comment: Ah I see, now it works - I hadn't been calling it with self.  Thank you.  As to the other question: why would the author define the method outside the class?  To me it's bordering on ridiculous - the class needs the method; without the method the class doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `def check_index(key)` still defines a method of `ArithmeticSequence`, regardless of what you call the first argument, which means you have to call it like a regular instance method (`self.check_index()`), and if you want to pass it an argument you have to add it after `self`. If you want to define a method on the class itself, you can use [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar(key):
        return key

    @classmethod
    def baz(cls, key):
        return key

    def quux(self):
        print(Foo.bar("abcd"), Foo.baz("abcd"))

Foo().quux()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `ArithmeticSequence` is not a new-style class. Check [this](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/)
2. You have 2 options:

   1. Add `self` to `check_index`. In the class, you will use it as `self.check_index(key)`. You will need to instantiate an `ArithmeticSequence` class object.
   2. Add `@staticmethod` before `check_index`. You will use it as `ArithmeticSequence.check_index(key)`

Comment: Would it become a new-style class if it were defined like this:  `class ArithmeticSequence(object)`?:

Comment: Yes. New-style class is more pythonic, and it enables to use decorator like `@staticmethod`. @JL_SO